# Using file content as arguments multiple times

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have one text file with names of a bunch of `.txt` files (not full path names) that exist in a directory. Each of the files, have a (full) path to another file which I would like to delete.

Suppose I have a file named "`list.txt`" and in it there are names of text files

```
pathtodelete1.txt
pathtodelete2.txt
something else that is the same as pathtodelete.txt
```

Each one of these files has a one path stored inside, for example `pathtodelete1.txt` contains `/directory/randomfilename.txt`

I have tried putting together `xargs` in many ways with no success.

Comment: This seems pretty convoluted. Can't you keep a single file with the paths to delete?

Comment: No... Hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a limited test, this worked for me:

```
cat list.txt | xargs cat | xargs rm
```

Since you are using this to delete files, you might want to test it with a non-destructive command first, e.g.

```
cat list.txt | xargs cat | xargs echo
```

Comment: UUOC `xargs cat <list.txt | xargs -r rm`

Comment: Just a caution: filenames that contain newlines (unusual but possible) will throw errors trying to remove them.

Comment: `xargs` by default also splits the input on any white space, so this won't work if any of the files involved have white space in their names. (like the one in the example)

Comment: @ilkkachu you can change the delimiter for xargs with -d '\n'

Comment: @novice, in GNU xargs, yes

Answer (score 0):

This script should do what you want. You can comment the `echo` statements (or omit them entirely) if you don't want a report on what it is doing.

Remove the `:` from the beginning of the `rm` statement when you are satisfied it will do what you want, and then it really will delete the named files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Look in list.txt for files containing items to delete
while IFS= read -r file
do
    echo "Considering $file" >&2

    # Read the path to delete from the file
    path="$(cat "$file" 2>/dev/null)"

    # If it looks like a pathname try to delete it
    if [[ "$path" =~ ^/ ]] && [[ -f "$path" ]]
    then
        echo "> $path" >&2
        : rm -f "$path"
    fi
done <list.txt
```

Comment: I was trying to work out whether `list.txt` was an example of "one of the files". Re-reading the question again, after your comment I'll revisit the code. Thanks @don_crissti

Comment: @don_crissti I think that's better now

Answer (score 0):

```
while read TXT; do head -1 $TXT | xargs rm; done < list.txt
```